# Get Woocommerce Orders list screen

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show Order screen in my plugin menu. The screen like that:

[Woocommerce Orders Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xZ0V.png)

Please tell me how to call this block into my plugin menu

Answer (score 2):

seeing you havent gotten an answer, I made my own custom one (its not identical and absolutelly not optimal, but atleast it works)
All methods I use are from here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

```
<table class="widefat">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="row-title">Ordre-ID</th>
                                    <th>Customer ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>adress</th>
                                    <th>note</th>
                                    <th>button</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                            <?php
    global $woocommerce;
$filters = array(
    'post_status' => 'completed',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);


                            $loop = new WP_Query($filters);

                            while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                $loop->the_post();
                                $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);
                                $items = $order->get_items();

                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td class="row-title"><a href=""><?=$order->get_order_number(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><a href=""><?=$order->get_customer_id(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?=$order->get_formatted_shipping_full_name(); ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$order->get_shipping_address_1(); ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$order->get_customer_note(); ?></td>
                                        <td><input type="button" class="button" id="order_id-<?=$order->get_order_number();?>" value="Send" data-id="order_id-<?=$order->get_order_number();?>"></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php

                             }
                             ?>
                         </tbody>

                     </table>
```